# Pressing the key b repeats the word 'set' indefinitely

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, inputrc

So, whenever I press the key <kbd>b</kbd> or tap two fingers on my touchpad while on the terminal, the cursor prints the word `set` indefinitely many times. I didn't have this problem recently, but I do remember modifying some files (unsuccessfully).

Unfortunately, I don't remember what files I modified and what I changed there that lead me to this situation. Can someone suggest where this may be stemming from?

Comment: Only at a shell prompt, or also in other circumstances? Chances are that it's a syntax error either in your `.inputrc` or in a `bind …` command in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115462/why-did-my-d-break-when-i-screwed-up-a-bind, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178637/why-is-bind-inputrc-causing-my-up-right-slash-key-to-be-disabled-unti

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' thanks, the syntax error was indeed in the inputrc file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "bind ~/.inputrc" causing my up-right slash key ('/') to be disabled until I re-login?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178637/why-is-bind-inputrc-causing-my-up-right-slash-key-to-be-disabled-unti)

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' yes, my problem was also caused by bind statement in .inputrc which I had put there after disabling the bell sound. Thanks so much for the input!